# How to get all data with Find in Gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I want to 2 data in the same table with for loop but just the last data display in products

```
rows, err := configs.DB.Table("carts").Select("product_id").Where("user_id = ? ", user_id).Rows()

    defer rows.Close()

    if err != nil {
        g.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        configs.DB.ScanRows(rows, &product_id)
    }



for _, id:= range product_id {
    
        configs.DB.Table("products").Where("id = ? ", id).Find(&products)


    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i use this to join 2 table using gorm

```
if err := db.Table("employee").Select("department.id, employee.department_id, employeeContact.employee_id").Joins("JOIN department on department.id = employee.department_id").Joins("JOIN employeeContact on employeeContact.id = employee.id").Find(&results).Error; err != nil {
    return err, ""
}
```